# Codename One Capturing tap event on Focused component

Tags: codenameone

What is the most appropriate way to capture tap events on a component?

I am using FocusListener, which works fine except for one thing - if a component that already has the focus is tapped, it does not refire focusGained (which makes sense).

Is there a better way to do this?

Is there a way to remove focus from a component?

Comment: To capture tap events on a `Component` there could be alternative ways. Of course, if it's a `Button` you can use `addActionListener`; if it's a `Container`, you can use a `Button` as leader component (every tap on that `Container` will invoke the `ActionListener` of the `Button`; if it's not a `Button` neither a `Container`, you can enclose it in a `Container` and set a `Button` as leader component. See: https://www.codenameone.com/manual/components.html#lead-component-sidebar and https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Container.html#setLeadComponent-com.codename1.ui.Component-

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to remove focus from a component although null is a valid value for focus. `FocusListener` is the way to track that.

I'm not sure if what you're trying to achieve is right for focus listener. On touch devices focus isn't as significant as it is on desktops so we don't use that listener much.

Comment: Well, I guess that is the question.  What should I use to receive events when my Container is touched?

Comment: You can use a pointer listener on the form to track low level events.You can also bind a pointer listener to the individual components.

Comment: Thanks - switching to use addPointerPressedListener instead of addFocusListener works much better, and is clearly the approach I wanted in the first place.  I do still need to setFocusable(true) on the container to make this work, as far as I can tell.